# java 7 update causes launcher to appear in mac application switcher

Tags: java, macos, jvm

My Mac is running OS X 10.6.  Previously I had Java 1.6.0_37 plus 1.7b06 installed, and 1.6 was set to be the default for command line use.

I frequently do command-line android builds.  Prior to installing the Java 1.7b09 update these would execute without the window focus ever leaving the terminal window from which I invoked the build.  Nothing "new" would appear in the application switcher.

*AFTER* installing 1.7b09, when I launch an android build from a command prompt, a new application ("Launcher") appears in the application switcher menu (command-tab) and window focus shifts from the terminal to this new Launcher app.

My question:  What setting should I twiddle to get back to the way things worked pre-1.7b09 install?

Answer (score 1):

Java version 1.6 was deployed by Apple, however, this changed since Java version 1.7. Oracle is [now responsible for the deployment of new releases](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_6.xml).

By the way, the `Launcher` application is a sandbox-like environment which is the default as of Java version 1.7. Personally, I think it's a bad idea to disable the sandbox-setting. It is there for a [reason](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076945/java-security/understanding-the-keys-to-java-security----the-sandbox-and-authentication.html).